# Duplicate Tab not copying sessionStorage in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tabs, session-storage

I have noticed that when tab is duplicated in IE 11 it is not copying/duplicated the sessionStorage data.  Is there any way to make it working in IE 11.

Same thing is working in Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: That is expected behavior of sessionStorage. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: above link says that it will create a new session if we open page in new window or another tab.  This will be same for all the browsers.  Here in my scenario it is no duplicating the sessionStorage for IE 11 but in other browser chrome or mozilla it is working fine.